# Complete function is not working in subscribe function

Tags: rxjs

I am newbie at rxjs.
I think, in my code, complete function is not working.
(My node version is `v12.16.3`)

```js
const { interval } = require('../../rxjs.js'); // I used CDN
const { take } = require('../../rxjs.js');     // I used CDN

interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    take(5)
  )
  .subscribe(
    res => console.log('>', res),
    err => console.log(err),
    _ => console.log("COMPLETE")
  );
```

My result is this.

```sh
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
```

**But I think result should be this.**

```sh
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
COMPLETE
```

**In my result, there is no `COMPLETE`.**
But I set the complete function in `subscribe` function as parameter.
Anyone know this??

Comment: I pasted your code into [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-71361674?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) and it seems to work as you expect.

Comment: Your code as is should work, but I STRONGLY recommend you use pipeable operators instead of subscribe callbacks. It's much cleaner, easier to read, understand, and modify, and it allows for concurrency management. Using subscribe callbacks pushes you towards bad practices (like nested subscriptions, for example).